# Obtención de fecha en diferentes atributos

Tags: c++, date

Un saludo porgramadores.

Estoy declarando la siguiente clase en C++:

```
class Fecha {
public:
    Fecha();
    Fecha(int dia, int mes, int anio);
    Fecha(const Fecha& orig);
    virtual ~Fecha();
    int getDia();
    void setDia(const int dia);
    int getMes();
    void setMes(const int mes);
    int getAnio();
    void setAnio(const int anio);
private:
    int _dia;
    int _mes;
    int _anio;
};
```

Pues bien, resulta que tengo que decirle al constructor por defecto (el del fichero **.cpp**) que asigne a los atributos los datos correspondientes a la fecha actual. Me he mirado con detenimiento el siguiente post: [How to get current time and date in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/997946/how-to-get-current-time-and-date-in-c)

No he sacado nada en claro, pues yo no quiero obtener la fecha cono un **string** ni nada por el estilo, sino que a cada variable (atributo) se le asigne el dato que lleva por nombre. Pero no he encontrado la forma de hacerlo. Tan solo dos códigos los sacaban por separado:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main ()
{
  time_t current_time;
  struct tm  local_time;

  time ( &current_time );
  localtime_s(&local_time, &current_time);

  int Year   = local_time.tm_year + 1900;
  int Month  = local_time.tm_mon + 1;
  int Day    = local_time.tm_mday;

  int Hour   = local_time.tm_hour;
  int Min    = local_time.tm_min;
  int Sec    = local_time.tm_sec;

  return 0;
}
```

Este, me deja a entender que falta una parte del mismo, pues `localtime_s` no se reconoce.

```
#include <boost/date_time/gregorian/gregorian.hpp>
#include <iostream>
using namespace boost::gregorian;

int main()
{
    date d = day_clock::universal_day();
    std::cout << d.day() << " " << d.month() << " " << d.year();
}
```

Este otro, utiliza una librería que, desde luego, poco de "por defecto" tiene, y que menos aún puedo descargar teniendo en cuenta que este proyecto debe poder ejecutarse en cualquier PC (importante, no solo en Windows).

Por lo tanto, me quedo sin ideas para obtener la fecha.

Muchas gracias una vez más por su ayuda.
Saludos.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No te reconoce `localtime_s( )` porque esa es una función POSIX, solo disponible en sistemas que cumplan dicho estándar.

El estándar ISO dispone de una función muy similar y que si debería estar disponible en cualquier plataforma: [`localtime( )`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/localtime):

```
#include <ctime>

Fecha::Fecha( ) {
  time_t timePtr = std::time( nullptr );
  tm *timeStruct = std::localtime( &timePtr );

  _dia = timeStruct->tm_mday;
  _mes = timeStruct->tm_mon + 1;
  _anio = timeStruct->tm_year + 1900;
}
```

No obstante, ya que estás en C++, puedes usar las funciones disponibles en este lenguaje (a partir de C++11):

```
#include <chrono>
#include <ctime>

Fecha::Fecha( ) {
  auto currTime = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t( std::chrono::system_clock::now( ) );
  tm *timeStruct = std::localtime( &currTime );

  _dia = timeStruct->tm_mday;
  _mes = timeStruct->tm_mon + 1;
  _anio = timeStruct->tm_year + 1900;
}
```

Como ves, no es que exista mucha diferencia. El trabajo real lo sigue realizando [`localtime( )`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/localtime).